# Bitmaps don't show up on the Canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm currently working on a small game for Android. I'm using Canvas and its drawBitmap method to draw the game-level. For this I have somewhat ported the XNA principle (so Update - Draw Loop and so on).

I have also added a "drawStaticParts" method. I use this method to draw certain parts only once. This method is called before the Update-Draw Loop starts. In this method I draw (with a Canvas) onto a Bitmap. This Bitmap is later used to "restore" the old state in Draw before I draw the dynamic parts (just like a call to drawColor(Color.Black) would).

This works perfectly fine. But only for the background, which is also drawn with the drawBitmap method. As soon as I try to add other bitmaps, they won't get displayed. I already checked if the background may override the other bitmaps, but the background draw call happens way before any other drawBitmap call. I also don't get any exceptions or similar.

Here is the code-fragment in question:

```
    public void drawStaticParts(Canvas c) {
    c.drawBitmap(TextureManager.getTexture(Element.getBackgroundID(), backgroundImg), null, new RectF(0, 0, Element.getResolution_width(), Element.getResolution_height()), null);
    for(int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            Element temp = spielfeld[i][j];
            if(temp != null)
            {
                if(Element.isStatic(temp))
                {
                    float x = i * Element.getElement_width();
                    float y = j * Element.getElement_height();
                    RectF place = new RectF(x, y, Element.getElement_width(), Element.getElement_height());
                    Log.w("MS:doDraw", "Draw at " + x + ", " + y + " with w=" + Element.getElement_width() + " and h=" + Element.getElement_height());
                    c.drawBitmap(TextureManager.getTexture(temp.getTextureID(), sceneryID), null, place, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I checked all values in question: everything is fine. The width and height is each 40 as supposed, the coordinates fit as well. I don't know any further.

I shall be eternally gratefull for any kind of help/advice. Thank you in advance.

PS: I also tried some of the solutions mentioned in threads with similar problems but nothing worked.

Answer (score 2):

you can't draw the static parts only once..

you should draw them **every loop**

because even if they are static every time you draw the dinamic parts you are overriding the current canvas and therefore you cant see the static parts..

EDIT: then the problem should be in the

```
TextureManager.getTexture(temp.getTextureID(), sceneryID)
```

check the parameters...

Comment: "This Bitmap is later used to "restore" the old state in Draw before I draw the dynamic parts (just like a call to drawColor(Color.Black) would)."
This bitmap is drawn every loop. But the initial drawBitmap calls only happen once.  
And as said: It works fine with the first drawBitmap call (the background)

Comment: No I already checked all of them and they are correct. Works exactly like in the call for the background and the call doesn't return null which means he shoud atleast draw something.

Comment: I also tried to add the parameters hardcoded, but the problem persisted

Comment: I can only be there. It's the only function that draws till now and the background is drawn fine. What else could it be?

Comment: thats exacly what i am wondering...but it can only be in the drawBitmap() parameters...and the 'place' looks fine so its in the first parameter for sure...notice that it should be a bitmap you should check it somehow...

Comment: it is. I checked the height and width of the returned Bitmap. For some reason it is 60 each allthough the original .png is 40x40. But this shouldn't be the problem as the background image is also bigger as a Bitmap than the original .jpg and it works fine. I also tried to change the type of the other parts to .jpg instead of .png but it didn't work either. I also checked the toString of the returned Bitmap, it seems fine.

Bitmap toString: android.graphics.Bitmap@412b2068

I also checked place: all parameters are correct and the coordinates are in-bounds